# Failed to verify bitcode in Stripe.framework/Stripe: error: Platform None is not supported while distributing build

Tags: ios, xcode, stripe-payments, xcode10.1

When I tried to distribute the app with AdHoc after archive, I got this error

**Failed to verify bitcode in Stripe.framework/Stripe:
error: Platform None is not supported**

Could you please tell me why this error is showing?

I am using Xcode 10.1.

Please find the attachment below:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you trying to upload to? The App Store?  You don't upload adhoc builds to the App Store.

Comment: Sorry, I was distributing the app after Archive with Adhoc. not uploading.